# Using a Custom post type, add a meta tag for Rank Math SEO WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, custom-post-type, meta-tags

I'm using Rank Math SEO WordPress plugin for my blog website . I'm using a custom post type in my Wordpress theme and custom post tag field , for regular posts Rank Math adding a meta tag to `wp_head` like this : `<meta property="article:tag" content="TAG_TEXT_HERE">` , for each regular post tag .

But when I insert my custom tags inside custom post type tag field , Rank Math can't detect those custom tags .

Can you help me please How can I add `<meta property="article:tag" content="TAG_TEXT_HERE">` for each custom tag inside `wp_head` inside `<head></head>` tag ?

Comment: What is the custom post type that you are using? Try to be more clear, adding all necessary details. Also, `TAG_TEXT_HERE`need to be replaced with something related to the current custom post, what is it?